# Xpath 2.0 functions not working in Java using Saxon

Tags: java, selenium, saxon, xpath-2.0

I'm writing a simple code to scrape data from the web page using selenium and xpath2.0 function.

Since Selenium supports only xpath1.0 functions, I am trying to use Saxon.jar

1. I have downloaded and extracted the Saxon9he.jar files into the path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\ext"
2. I have created a file "jaxp.properties" with the following lines:

       javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
       javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory","net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl
3. Also included my jar files in the eclipse library.

But, I am not able to fetch the values with the Xpath2.0 functions.

In my code, if I use

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
```

instead of

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);
```

I am able to use the xpath1.0 functions. But I need Xpath2.0 function. please guide me in this.

My code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFunctionResolver;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathVariableResolver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import net.sf.saxon.lib.NamespaceConstant;
import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;


public class XpathCheckClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathFactoryConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException{


WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();

dr.get("http://s15.a2zinc.net/clients/hartenergy/midstream17/Public/eBooth.aspx?Nav=False&BoothID=137384");
try {

Thread.sleep(3000);

} catch (Exception e) {

}

String source = dr.getPageSource();

Document doc = null;

try {

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

doc = db.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader(source)));

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"+NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON, "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);

//    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();   ---> default xpath factory

XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("if(//h2) then //h2 else //h1");

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println(nodes.getLength());

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent()); 
}


dr.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent releases of Saxon no longer advertise themselves as JAXP XPath services, so you need to instantiate the XPath factory explicitly:

```
XPathFactory xf = new net.sf.saxon.XPathFactoryImpl();
```

Comment: Just to add a little explanation: the reason the Saxon JAR doesn't expose itself as an XPath processor is that too many applications were picking it up by accident, when they were written and tested to work with XPath 1.0. Unfortunately the JAXP interface doesn't provide any way to say "please find me an XPath 2.0 processor".